# Media Queries for Microsoft Surface Pro 3 & Surface Pro 4

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries

What's the best way to write media queries for the Surface Pro 3 & 4? in both Landscape & Portrait views?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be not to write media queries for specific devices at all, but rather to identify logical places in your design to fold elements in or break them out accordingly, to account for devices of any width.

See this article for more info: [Google Developers—How to Choose Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/how-to-choose-breakpoints?hl=en)

In practice, the resolutions of those two devices you mentioned are 2160x1440 (Surface Pro 3) and 2736x1824 (Surface Pro 4). So, instead of setting those four breakpoints for your media queries, one logical approach would be to design for "greater than 2000px", "between 1200px and 2000px", and "under 1200px"—the first rule handling both devices you mentioned in landscape mode (also handling common desktop resolutions), the second rule handling both devices in portrait mode (and many other common portable devices), and the last rule handling devices of all sizes under 1200px.

This is just one way to tackle the problem, I'd recommend you research more carefully the common theories behind responsive design and breakpoint selection.

Comment: Thanks @ian m. I'm using the standard 4 breakpoints, and understand that writing queries for specific devices is not by any means a best practice, but in this situation we have to placate someone who is a big Microsoft Surface fan and likes to read in portrait view. Is there a more specific query for the 3 and the 4 you could recommend?